# Postgres' filter (where ...) and the ANSI standard

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4, ansi-sql

I am wondering if the Postgres' `filter (where ...)` conforms to the ANSI standard?

I am unsure since it isn't a feature in most RDBMS that I have come across and I can't seem to find a definitive answer anywhere.

Sorry if the "is x ANSI" questions are monotonous.

Comment: Yes, this is part of Standard SQL.

Comment: Hi, thanks responding so quickly. Do you have a reference at hand for where I can find this information?

Comment: Unfortunately, the SQL standard isn't freely available. [Markus Winand](https://modern-sql.com/feature/filter) states that "*SQL:2003 introduced the filter clause as part of the optional feature “Advanced OLAP operations” (T612)*"

Comment: Thats's unfortunate, I had been using "sql in a nutshell" as a resource but the filter clause is not mentioned in the book. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @OmjjICmA . . . There are lots of things in the standard that are not going to be in any particular book -- and I don't think any database fully supports the standard.

Comment: https://developer.mimer.com/sql-2016-validator/ says _Conforms to SQL-2016
The following feature outside SQL-2016 is used:
T612, Advanced OLAP operations
T611, Elementary OLAP operations_

Answer (score 1):

ISO/IEC 9075-2:2003 (and later versions of the standard) define the `FILTER` clause in chapter 10, verse 9:

> ## 10.9 <aggregate function>
>
> ### Function
>
> Specify a value computed from a collection of rows.
>
> ### Format
>
> ```
> <aggregate function> ::=
>     COUNT <left paren> <asterisk> <right paren> [ <filter clause> ]
>   | <general set function> [ <filter clause> ]
>   | <binary set function> [ <filter clause> ]
>   | <ordered set function> [ <filter clause> ]
>
> [...]
>
> <filter clause> ::=
>     FILTER <left paren> WHERE <search condition> <right paren>
> ```

Note that this is not required by the standard: it is optional feature T612.

Comment: Thanks @jarlh , I added it to the answer.